# Adding and Removing Nodes in D3js Force Graph

Tags: javascript, graph, d3.js

I am loading `json` from database and creating a `json` file which loads fine. Now I don't know which steps to take for making the nodes responsive in a Force-Directed Graph. I need to remove and add new nodes and their links.

```
force.nodes(json.nodes)
    .links(json.links)
    .start();

initNodes(json);
```

How can I make this more dynamic or update it without resetting the whole visualization?

I have seen this question a couple of times not being answered so I hope someone can post and give a guide.

Answer (score 15):

Adding nodes/links to my D3 force graph was very confusing until I better understood the way I was adding the initial set of nodes.

Assuming a `<g>` is what you'd like to use for your nodes:

```
// Select the element where you'd like to create the force layout
var el = d3.select("#svg");

// This should not select anything
el.selectAll("g")

// Because it's being compared to the data in force.nodes() 
    .data(force.nodes())

// Calling `.enter()` below returns the difference in nodes between 
// the current selection and force.nodes(). At this point, there are
// no nodes in the selection, so `.enter()` should return 
// all of the nodes in force.nodes()
    .enter()

// Create the nodes
    .append("g")
    .attr("id", d.name)
    .classed("manipulateYourNewNode", true);
```

Now let's make that function that will add a node to the layout once the graph has been initialized!

`newNodeData` is an object with the data you'd like to use for your new node.
`connectToMe` is a string containing the unique id of a node you'd like to connect your new node to.

```
function createNode (newNodeData, connectToMe) {
    force.nodes().push(newNodeData);
    el.selectAll("g")
       .data(force.nodes(), function(datum, index) { return index })
```

The function given as the optional second argument in `.data()` is run once for each node in the selection and again for each node in `force.nodes()`, matching them up based on the returned value. If no function is supplied, a fallback function is invoked, which returns the `index` (as above).

However, there's most likely going to be a dispute between the index of your new selection (I believe the order is random) and the order in `force.nodes()`. Instead you'll most likely need the function to return a property that is unique to each node.

This time, `.enter()` will only return the node you're trying to add as `newData` because no key was found for it by the second argument of `.data()`.

```
       .enter()
       .insert("g", "#svg")
       .attr("id", d.name)
       .classed("manipulatYourNewNode", true);

    createLink(connectToMe, newNodeData.name);

    force.start();
}
```

The function createLink (defined below) creates a link between your new node and your node of choice.

Additionally, [the d3js API states that force.start() should be called after updating the layout](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Force-Layout#wiki-start).

**Note:** Calling `force.stop()` at the very beginning of my function was a huge help for me when I was first trying to figure out how to add nodes and links to my graph.

```
function createLink (from, to) {
    var source = d3.select( "g#" + from ).datum(),
        target = d3.select( "g#" + to ).datum(),
        newLink = {
            source: source,
            target: target,
            value: 1
        };
    force.links().push(newLink);
```

The code below works under the assumptions that:

1. `#links` is the wrapper element that contains all of your link elements
2. Your links are represented as `<line>` elements:

   ```
   d3.select("#links")
       .selectAll("line")
       .data(force.links())
       .enter()
       .append("line");
   ```

Comment: Good answer on how to add a node, but forgets to mention how to **remove** a node.

Answer (score 7):

You can see an example of how to append new nodes and relationships here:
http://bl.ocks.org/2432083

Getting rid of nodes and relationships is slightly trickier, but you can see the process here:
http://bl.ocks.org/1095795

Comment: The important part is to save the value return from .data method in var (say x) and call x.exit().remove() at the end of the method.