# refreshing graph in d3js

Tags: svg, d3.js, nodes

I've been working with the d3.js library for a bit now and I love the visualizations, but I'm having a hard time achieving exactly what I need.

What I'm trying to do:

- I've constructed a graph with a central node that is styled differently from the other nodes.  The visualization has a label in the center (a special node with id=node0), and connected to that label are the other styled nodes.
- When user hits submit, an ajax call refreshes the javascript information and restarts the simulation with new nodes.

I've set things up in the same way as I see here:

[Adding and Removing Nodes in D3js Force Graph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11606214/add-and-remove-nodes-in-d3js)

My refresh function looks like this:

```
 function restart() 
 {

   for ( ii = 0; ii < nodes.length; ii++ ) {
   var n = nodes[ii];

   if (n.id == 0)
   {
      n.fixed = true;
      n.x = w/2;
      n.y = h/2;
      continue;
   }

   mult1 = [ -1.0, -1.0, 1.0, 1.0 ];
   mult2 = [ 1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 1.0 ];
   n.x = w/2 + ii*5 * mult1[ii%4];
   n.y = h/2 + ii*5 * mult2[ii%4];
   }


 var node = svg.selectAll("g.node")
  .data(nodes, function(d) { return d.id;});

 var nodeEnter = node.enter().append("g")
  .attr("id", function(d) { return "node" + d.id })
  .attr("class", "node")
  .call(force.drag);

 node.exit().remove();

 node.each( function(d)  {

    if (d.id != 0)
    {
       n = svg.select("#node" + d.id);
       frame = n.append("svg:foreignObject")
         .attr("x", -1.0 * platewidth/2)
         .attr("y", -1.0 * plateheight/2)
         .attr("width", platewidth)
         .attr("height", plateheight)
         .on("click", showdetail)
         .on("tap", showdetail);
       frame.append("xhtml:div")
         .attr("class", "top-plate")
         .html(function(d) { return "<img src='/img/" + d.img + "'>" } );
       frame.append("xhtml:div")
         .attr("class", "btm-plate")
         .html( function (d) { return d.name });


       n.append("image")
         .attr("xlink:href", function(d) { return d.ownerimg })
         .attr("x", platewidth/2 - 35)
         .attr("y", plateheight/2 - 15)
         .attr("width", 30)
         .attr("height", 30)
         .on("click", showdetail)
         .on("tap", showdetail);

      n.append("image")
         .attr("xlink:href", function(d) { return d.houseimg })
         .attr("x", platewidth/2 - 70)
         .attr("y", plateheight/2 - 15)
         .attr("width", 30)
         .attr("height", 30)
         .on("click", showdetail)
         .on("tap", showdetail);
    }
    else
    {
        querytext = d.query;
        n = svg.select("#node" + d.id);
        n.append("text")
          .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
          .text(querytext);    

        n.attr("transform", function(d) {
           return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")";
        });    
    }

  });

    force.start();

 }
```

The problems I'm having:

- The second DIV element of the nodes (the one with the HTML element containing d.name) does not reposition in Chrome.  It works fine in Firefox, but in Chrome all these DIVs show up at 0,0.  Note that the first DIV of these nodes (which has the img tag), as well as all the images attached to the nodes, all show up fine and reposition properly.  It's just this second DIV which is not repositioning with the associated node.
- I can't get the label text of node0 to update/change correctly.  When I pass new text in (using d.query) that text overwrites the old text so that both show up.  I think I need to remove the "text" element associated with node0 first, but I'm not sure how to do that.
- Generally, I'm not really sure I'm using this library the right way.  The difficulty here stems from the fact that I'm attaching a lot to the nodes and that I have one special central node that behaves differently than the others.  So any pointers on how to do this better would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: An example would help. Do you have a working JSFiddle?

Comment: And I know that I sometimes have issues with my transitions in Chrome as well. Seems to cache things when I'm working on updating code. So when testing code, I usually stick with FF. Then things are usually fine in Chrome when it is finally in production.

Answer (score 0):

I think your second problrm can be solved by using

```
n.selectAll("text")
.attr("text-anchor", "middle")
.text(querytext);
```

instead of

```
n.append("text")
.attr("text-anchor", "middle")
.text(querytext);
```