# How to remove existing nodes in d3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js, visualization, data-visualization

I have already visit [add and remove nodes in D3js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11606214/add-and-remove-nodes-in-d3js?lq=1) but it don't solve my problem.

There are some nodes at first time, then I want to add nodes dynamically and want if node is already exists it update that nodes and don't do duplicate.

now it is making duplicate not updating existing ones.
 Here is main code and full code and working fiddle is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/qYStf/1/)

```
//handles node elements
var circles = svg.selectAll('g');


//update graph (called when needed)
function restart() {

/***************************************
    Draw circles (nodes)
****************************************/


circles = circles.data(data.nodes);

var g = circles.enter()
               .append("g")
               .attr("class", "gNode")
               .attr("cursor", "pointer")
               .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")"; })
               .call(force.drag);



g.append("circle")                      
.attr({
     "class": "node", 
     "cx": function(d) { return rScale(d.NumOccurrences); },
     "cy": function(d) { return rScale(d.NumOccurrences); },
     "r": function(d) { return rScale(d.NumOccurrences); }
 })             
 .style("fill", function(d, i) { return colors(i); })
 .style("stroke", "#000");



 g.append("text")
.attr({
    "x": function(d) { return rScale(d.NumOccurrences); },
    "y": function(d) { return rScale(d.NumOccurrences); },
    "font-family": "sans-serif",
    "font-size": "20px",
    "fill": "black",
    "text-anchor": "middle"
   })
   .text( function (d) { return d.name; });

   g.append("title")        
    .text(function(d) { return d.name; });

 // remove old nodes
 circles.exit().remove();

 // set the graph in motion
 force.start();
 }

// app starts here
restart();


 function dynamicAddNodes() {

var updatedata = {"name":"ios","NumOccurrences":"500","color":"green","x":0,"y":1}

data.nodes.push(updatedata);    

restart();
 }

 setInterval(dynamicAddNodes, 10000);
```

Answer (score 3):

try it:

```
circles = circles.data(data.nodes,function (d) {
     return d.id;
   });
```

that the node's Id is unique.

you can see : [jsfiddle.net/MoHSenMHS/5r62N/](http://jsfiddle.net/MoHSenMHS/5r62N/)

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is not the update nodes process, but the data you are updating them to.

When `restart()` runs, it doesn't remove any nodes from the data, it just adds them. Since the data is never taken away, nodes are never taken away. Each time the function is called, a new data node is added, and a new circle is added corresponding to that data node.

I've updated your example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/qYStf/4/) to show this behavior. Each time I change the data, I remove an entry from your data, and replace it with a new data point.

Comment: Thanks for reply. Let I explain you that what I want to do. **want to update radius of existing nodes and add new nodes**  **1** These are keywords stored in database. **2** first time it shows 20 nodes and size of radius based on number of time this keyword exists in database. **3** Now new keywords came in database or the some duplicate keywords added. **4** now after 10 seconds I call to database and retrieve keywords and want to update radius of existing nodes and add new nodes

Comment: Take a look at http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3808218. It shows the general update pattern in d3, with the next two examples showing how to do keyed data and transitions.

Basically, what you'll be doing is specifying what happens when data enters, leaves, and changes. You'll need a function that defines these behaviors, and then call that function each time you update your data.