# D3 Force Directed Graph - Removing Nodes

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js, force-layout

I am trying to incorporate [this example](https://gist.github.com/mbostock/1095795) for adding/removing nodes from a Force Directed Graph. I am able to add nodes just fine, and for some reason I am also able to remove the nodes I have added without issues. However when I try to remove any of the original nodes, the node is not removed from the display, and it also breaks many other nodes' links. However, it and it's links are properly removed from the JSON based on the logs.

[This example](http://bl.ocks.org/tgk/6068367) uses seemingly the same method as I do for removing nodes with splice.

[Here](https://bl.ocks.org/denisemauldin/cdd667cbaf7b45d600a634c8ae32fae5) also seems to use splice method though I don't fully follow the rest of what it is doing with filtering.

[There is also this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11606214/adding-and-removing-nodes-in-d3js-force-graph) that asks a somewhat similar thing though the answers only address adding.

I have tried exit/removing after the append which did not work. I have also tried using `.insert` instead of `.append`. The `console.log` during the `update()` function prints the JSON being used and it shows that nodes and links are all properly removed, but the display doesn't reflect that.

Relevant code is below.

Initializing/updating graph

```
//Get the SVG element
var svg = d3.select("svg");

var width = 960, height = 600;
var color = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory20);

var link = svg.append("g").selectAll(".link");
var node = svg.append("g").selectAll(".node");
var label = svg.append("g").selectAll(".label");

//Begin the force simulation
var simulation = d3.forceSimulation()
    .force("link", d3.forceLink().id(function (d) { return d.id; }).distance(50).strength(0.3))
    .force("charge", d3.forceManyBody().strength(-15))
    .force("center", d3.forceCenter(width / 2, height / 2));

//Highlight variables
var highlight_color = "blue";
var tHighlight = 0.05;

var config;

var linkedByIndex = {};

//Get the data
d3.json("/../../data.json", function (data) {
    //if (!localStorage.graph)
    //{
        localStorage.graph = JSON.stringify(data);
    //}
    update();
    forms();
});

function update() {

    config = JSON.parse(localStorage.graph);
    console.log(JSON.stringify(config));
    linkedByIndex = {};
    //Create an array of source,target containing all links
    config.links.forEach(function (d) {
        linkedByIndex[d.source + "," + d.target] = true;
        linkedByIndex[d.target + "," + d.source] = true;
    });

    //Draw links
    link = link.data(config.links);
    link.exit().remove();
    link = link.enter().append("line")
            .attr("class", "link")
            .attr("stroke-width", 2)
            .attr("stroke", "#888")
            //.attr("opacity", function (d) { if (d.target.radius > 7) { return 1 }; return 0; })
            .merge(link);         


    node = node.data(config.nodes);
    node.exit().remove();
    node = node.enter().append("circle")
            .attr("class", "node")
            .attr("r", function(d) { return d.radius; })
            .attr("fill", function (d) { return color(d.id); })
            .attr("stroke", "black")
        //  .attr("pointer-events", function (d) { if (d.radius <= 7) { return "none"; } return "visibleAll"; })
        //  .attr("opacity", function (d) { if (d.radius <= 7) { return 0; } return 1; })
            .call(d3.drag()
            .on("start", dragstarted)
            .on("drag", dragged)
            .on("end", dragended))
            .on("mouseover", mouseOver)
            .on("mouseout", mouseOut)
            .merge(node);

    label = label.data(config.nodes);
    label.exit().remove();
    label = label.enter().append("text")
            .attr("class", "label")
            .attr("dx", function (d) { return d.radius * 1.25; })
            .attr("dy", ".35em")
            .attr("opacity", function (d) { if (d.radius <= 7) { return 0; } return 1; })
            .attr("font-weight", "normal")
            .style("font-size", 10)
            .text(function (d) { return d.id; })
            .merge(label);

    //Add nodes to simulation
    simulation
        .nodes(config.nodes)
        .on("tick", ticked);

    //Add links to simulation
    simulation.force("link")
        .links(config.links);

    simulation.alphaTarget(0.3).restart();
}

//Animating by ticks function
function ticked() {
    node
        .attr("cx", function (d) { return d.x = Math.max(d.radius, Math.min(width - d.radius, d.x)); })
        .attr("cy", function (d) { return d.y = Math.max(d.radius, Math.min(height - d.radius, d.y)); });
    link
        .attr("x1", function (d) { return d.source.x; })
        .attr("y1", function (d) { return d.source.y; })
        .attr("x2", function (d) { return d.target.x; })
        .attr("y2", function (d) { return d.target.y; });
    label
        .attr("x", function (d) { return d.x = Math.max(d.radius, Math.min(width - d.radius, d.x)); })
        .attr("y", function (d) { return d.y = Math.max(d.radius, Math.min(height - d.radius, d.y)); });
}

//Using above array, check if two nodes are linked
function isConnected(node1, node2) {
    return linkedByIndex[node1.id + "," + node2.id] || node1.index == node2.index;
}
```

Adding/removing nodes and links.
ADDING works perfectly fine for both nodes and links this way.

```
function newNode(name, rad)
{
    if (name == "")
    {
        alert("Must specify name");
        return;
    }
    console.log("Adding node with name: " + name + " and radius: " + rad);
    var temp = JSON.parse(localStorage.graph);
    temp.nodes.push({ "id": name, "radius": Number(rad) });
    localStorage.graph = JSON.stringify(temp);
    update();
}

function newLink(source, target)
{
    var foundSource = false;
    var foundTarget = false;

    if (source == "" && target == "")
    {
        alert("Must specify source and target");
        return;
    }
    else if(source == "")
    {
        alert("Must specify source");
        return;
    }
    else if (target == "")
    {
        alert("Must specify target")
        return;
    }

    var temp = JSON.parse(localStorage.graph);

    for (var i=0; i < temp.nodes.length; i++)
    {
        if(temp.nodes[i]['id'] === source)
        {
            foundSource = true;
        }

        if(temp.nodes[i]['id'] === target)
        {
            foundTarget = true;
        }
    }

    if (foundSource && foundTarget) {
        temp.links.push({ "source": source, "target": target });
        localStorage.graph = JSON.stringify(temp);
        update();
    }
    else {
        alert("Invalid source or target");
        return;
    }

    return;
}

function removeLink(linkSource, linkTarget)
{

}

function removeNode(nodeName)
{
    var temp = JSON.parse(localStorage.graph);
    var found = false;

    if (nodeName == "")
    {
        alert("Must specify node name");
        return;
    }

    for(var i=0; i<temp.nodes.length; i++)
    {
        if(temp.nodes[i]['id'] === nodeName)
        {
            console.log("Removing node: " + nodeName);
            found = true;
            temp.nodes.splice(i, 1);
            temp.links = temp.links.filter(function (d) { return d.source != nodeName && d.target != nodeName; });
        }
    }

    if(!found)
    {
        alert("Node does not exist");
        return;
    }

    localStorage.graph = JSON.stringify(temp);

    update();
}
```

JSON Data is in the format

```
{
  "nodes":[
   {
      "id": "id1",
       "radius": 5},
   {
      "id: "id2",
       "radius": 6}
],

"links":[{
"source": "id1",
"target": "id2"    
]
}
```

Comment: Hi! I am trying to reproduce your problem here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/q53397252. I've made functions `newNode`, `newLink`, `removeNode`, and `removeLink` global, so you can call them in console. In my browser I do not see any errors after removing any of initial nodes.

Comment: I'm not able to use this site for some reason it just says "starting dev server" and never loads. How do you call functions from the console? Right now I am using some buttons so I can test using console to see if it works

Comment: Update: I tried running remove node from the console and it still doesn't properly update display. To clarify @YaroslavSergienko there are no errors that show up...but the display is not correct. Nodes will get jumbled and the 'removed' node which is no longer in the JSON is usually still there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default d3 joins data by index, so after you remove node, it assigns data incorrectly. The solution is to pass second argument to `.data` function. You need to replace

```
node = node.data(config.nodes);
```

with

```
node = node.data(config.nodes, d => d.id);
```

You can also do this for links, but if their styles are equal (i.e. they only differ by `x1`, `x2`, `y1` and `y2`) it will make no difference.

Update: you should do this for labels as well

```
label = label.data(config.nodes, d => d.id);
```

Comment: I tried changing this but I'm seeing the same result. Is there some documentation regarding the way data is joined that I can reference in this case? It does seem something like that could be the cause as colors are mixed up as well when removing.

Comment: The most comprehensive about joins it this: https://bost.ocks.org/mike/selection/#key. 
Can you share example with colors and steps to reproduce the problem?

Comment: The color of the node is defined by its ID. Here is standard graph that is drawn by my code: https://imgur.com/CcTL4mL

Next I execute removeNode('CCC')

This is result: https://imgur.com/a/d0ThkhU

Most nodes stay the same, some change color and name. (KYC changes to MAL and MAL changes to CCC) However JSON shows no nodes with name "CCC" being loaded.

Comment: I haven't noticed, that you also have labels, so you should pass second argument for them as well